# How to set google font programmatically in Android

Tags: android

How to set google font programmatically in Android

> App is crash   Caused by:
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Font resource ID
> #0x7f090002 could not be retrieved.

```
 val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(applicationContext, R.font.halant)
 appVersionName.typeface = typeface
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
        app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
        app:fontProviderQuery="Halant"
        app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
</font-family>
```

[image]

Comment: can you show these XMLs content?

Comment: Where are your `ttf` files?

Comment: i don't have ttf file, i just add google font using android studio

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Answer (score 3):

Though above two answers are correct, I will give you step-by-step details about "*Downloadable Fonts*" so that other will understand.

> Note: A device must have Google Play services version 11 or higher to
> use the Google Fonts provider.

1. In the **Layout Editor**, select a TextView, and then under **Properties**, select **fontFamily > More Fonts**.
   [image]
2. Select the font want and make sure you choose *create downloadable font* (creates xml file in your *font* folder) and click **OK**.
   [image]

> Android Studio automatically generates the relevant XML files that are
> needed to render the font correctly in your app.

Now, you can directly add it in TextView like this:

```
android:fontFamily="@font/halant_light"
```

Or use Downloadable Fonts programmatically like this:

```
val request = FontRequest(
        "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
        "com.google.android.gms",
        "Halant", //your font
        R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs
    )
val callback = object : FontsContract.FontRequestCallback() {

    override fun onTypefaceRetrieved(typeface: Typeface) {
        // Your code to set the font goes here
    }

    override fun onTypefaceRequestFailed(reason: Int) {
        // Your code to deal with the failure goes here
        
    }
}
FontsContractCompat.requestFont(mContext, request, callback, mHandler)
```

If you don't want the above programmatic way you can use the below code which I tested and working perfectly:

```
val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(applicationContext, R.font.halant_light)
fontText.typeface = typeface
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val typeface = Typeface.create("sans-serif-condensed", Typeface.BOLD)
textView.typeface = typeface
```